# Scipy.stats norm vs lognorm

Tags: python, distribution

To the find the probability a number is greater than x using `scipy.stats.norm` you could write a function like this `1-scipy.stats.norm(55.98,12.29).cdf(64)` returning 0.257 meaning that given a mean of 55.98 and a standard deviation of 12.29, there is a 25.7% probability your random observation will be greater than 64? If I wanted to find the logarithmic normal distribution could I do the same with the `scipy.stats.lognorm` function? `1-scipy.stats.lognorm(55.98,12.29).cdf(64)` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the correct interpretation for the normal distribution.

For lognorm, the scipy parameterization is a little weird.

Suppose X is a normally distributed random variable with mean mu and std dev sigma.
If Y is defined such that X = ln(Y), then Y has a log normal distribution.

To represent Y in scipy, you do this:

```py
from scipy.stats import lognorm
from math import exp

#using smaller numbers for this example
mu=1
sigma=2
X=norm(mu,sigma)
X.mean() #1.0
X.var() # 4.0

Y = lognorm(s=sigma,scale=exp(mu))
Y.mean() # 20.085536923187668
Y.var() #21623.037001313976
```

This produces the same result as the wikipedia lognorm formulas for:

- mean = exp(mu + sigma^2/2)
- variance = (exp(sigma^2)-1)*(exp(2*mu+sigma^2)

In all cases in scipy, the .cdf(x) method gives you the probability that the random variable is less than or equal to x.